# How to get text flush with the page

Tags: html, css

I made an unordered list by imitating the code of another website, http://jointhekvlt.com/. (The website is a clothing website but does contain some explicit photos.) The website has an unordered list it uses as its navigation bar and it has a padding-top to get the nav come down from the top. My code is the same but my list never seems to be flush with the top and requires no padding. Why is that?

```
<body>
<div id="header">
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
<li>Blah</li>
<li>Blah</li>
<li>Blah</li>
<li>Blah</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div> 
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PaperStSoap/BgETs/1/

Comment: It doesn't look like they are using any padding either.

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly is wrong.  Are you overlooking the `padding-top: 10px` line or am I not understanding your issue?

Comment: I see the padding-top: 10px and from tinkering it was used to being the list down a bit so it isn't flush with the top. I just want to know why my code doesn't have the text flush with the top.

Comment: @PaperSt.Soapthe top-right menu in your fiddle is not flush with the top of the page because `.wrapper ul` has `padding-top: 10px;` on it. Get rid of that and it's hugging the top.

Answer (score 0):

I interpreted your question to mean you want the text with some separation from the top and side of the page. Some general CSS that might help you get what you are trying to achieve:

```
(Adding the class="nav" to your UL)
.nav {
  display: inline-table;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  float: right;
  }
/* additional menu styling here*/
```